# Power calculations for difference in means of proportions

Tags: proportion, statistical-power, group-differences

How would you conduct power analysis for comparing means of a response that goes from 0 to 1? -- e.g. comparing the mean test scores of two groups of students, where the score can range 0-100%?

This seems like it should be different than conducting power analysis comparing two means of a continuous response variable (where you'd assume observations to be normally distributed), unless you're willing to assume that the 0-100% scores are close-enough-to normal. I know you that there are ways of conducting power analysis for comparing differences in proportion when you have a binary outcome, e.g. comparing the % female for two groups of people, which restricts the group means also to a range from 0-1, but that doesn't seem quite right either.